# I want to store user information in postgresql using postgresql and node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to add user information like Firstname, Lastname, email and Phone number and
gender what
will be the good method to store user information whether I should put all this detail in user
table or make new table to store user information If I make new how to connect with user table
so I can show user information in profile page rather than in registration side

Here is my user table that I make for registration and and login things, Is that good? To add user information over here rather than in separate table.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

Here is my car detail things so when user done login things he/she will add cars and with name and model this will appear in database.

```
CREATE TABLE car_detail (
    car_id PRIMARY KEY,
    car_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    car_model varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
);
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Is your attempt not working in some way?

Comment: If it's 1 to 1 relationship between the rows in the user table and user details table, then I would recommend just to have a single table. If you are going to manage permissions per object/table and you want different people to have different permissions on the table access, then it might be a reason for you to separate the data, but I doubt it's your case

Comment: "*should I put all this detail in user table?*" - yes of course!

Comment: @Alexander Even then you can grant permissions on the individual table columns